# EX3300 can not use irb.x, so how to access the layer-3 address?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

EX3300 can not use irb.x,

I have a Juniper EX4300 convergence layer Switch, in it there are `irb` interfaces. such as `irb.3`, and if I have another EX4300 for access layer, I can set vlan `l3-interface irb.3` without create irb.3 in the second access layer switch.

but now the second switch is a EX3300 device, I can not set `vlan3`'s l3-interface to `irb.3`, only can set `vlan.3`. but if so, how can I use the vlan3 to access the layer3 address( EX4300's `irb.3` address) in my EX3300?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your Ethernet switching configuration setup by irb instead of vlan 
You may get a better answer by pasting your EX3300 configurations.

In my guess, the following configurations are on your EX3300 switch.

> set interfaces vlan unit 0 family inet address xx.xx.xx.xx/xx 
>   set vlans default l3-interface vlan.3

These VLAN settings should be the following IRB settings:

> set interfaces irb unit 0 family inet address xx.xx.xx.xx/xx 
>   set vlans default l3-interface irb.3

[Juniper IRB Settings](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/topic-map/irb-and-bridging.html)

Comment: I confused EX2300 and EX3300. EX3300 is an old switch and it does not support IRB CLI syntax.

Comment: Newer switches comes with so-called **ELS** (Enhanced Layer-2 Software). In software with ELS support you use `irb` interfaces instead of `vlan`.